# Why did Jordan kill herself?

Tags: character, terminator-series, the-sarah-connor-chronicles

In *Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles* [S1E3: "The Turk"](https://terminator.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_103:_The_Turk), John and Cameron are entering a new school. When they came to the school they saw some kind of drawing on the school wall and they also see this kind of drawing a few times in the school. There was a girl named Jordan in the school upset about it and in the end she commits suicide. John tries to save Jordan, but Cameron wouldn't let him. What is the meaning of the drawing on the school wall and why did Jordan kill herself?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Jordan is the girl in the third image, with blonde hair.

The images suggest that Jordan did something inappropriate with someone (probably a teacher) and that someone else knows, and they are slowly revealing it. Jordan is afraid that people, particularly her parents, will find out the truth. As they reveal more about the door scene, they are also revealing the name Jordan.